# Verbose Software Updater?

Tags: update-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After approving and authenticating the present batch of titles in the update, the best the GUI can do is to show a list of the past titles--already downloaded to the computer during this session--but tells me nothing about how much more has yet to come in the remainder of the download session.

Is there a) some other Software Updater window that I'm missing that can be shown, b) can a "MB queued" field be added to the current GUI, c) can the queued titles be ghosted in, or perhaps d) is there even a CLI command I can give or e) is there a widget I can launch to tell me how long the download queue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in terminal.

It shows full list of upgraded packages and the progress in MB.